# container inside nav puts toggler over brand with hi zoom

Tags: html, nav, twitter-bootstrap-4

With `<div class="content">` inside `<nav>` causes toggle puts over brand:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md" id="nav-global" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">somenxavier</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsing-menu" title="Menu"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon">&#9776;</span></button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="collapsing-menu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.md.html" title="About">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

[image]

without content, everything is fine

[image]

I have a zoom of 300% and I use alpha 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in alpha 6: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22028
it will be fixed in the Beta release.